# Given a campgrounds array, a type of view as a string, and the party size as a number, return an array with campsite numbers for the matching sites

Tags: javascript

I am into Javascript few days now. I need your help if I am forgetting anything. Thanks in advance.

These are instructions:

Write a function findMyCampsites. Given a campgrounds array, a type of view as a string, and the party size as a number, return an array with campsite numbers for the matching campsites.

currently available campsites (isReserved === false),
with the view that matches the input string (e.g. ocean or forest),
that can host the party size of the input number, or greater,

If no sites are available, return the string 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party'

```js
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, string, number) {
  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if(
    campgrounds[i].isReserved === false &&
    campgrounds[i].view === string &&
    campgrounds[i].partySize === number
    ) {
      return campgrounds[i].number;
    } else {
      return "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do exactly as you've asked:

```
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, string, number) {
  const campsites = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if(
    campgrounds[i].isReserved === false &&
    campgrounds[i].view === string &&
    campgrounds[i].partySize >= number
    ) {
      campsites.push(campgrounds[i].number);
    }
  }
  if (campsites.length === 0) {
    return "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party";
  } else {
    return campsites;
  }
}
```

But, I would like to highlight a couple of things, firstly, you would want to make the function parameters much more descriptive. I.e instead of the second parameter being called `string`, maybe call it something like `siteType` and instead of the third argument being `number`, try something like `requiredSpaces`. Also, It's a little odd for this function to return a string (if no sites are found) and an array (if sites are found). Usually you would generally want the function to only return a single type, but if that's what the brief is asking you to do, then so be it. Just a couple of things for you to think about as you progress through your coding career.

Comment: it only passed 1 example test we are missing something

Comment: Which ones did it fail?

Comment: It worked man, Thank you. Only thing missing in campsites.push(campgrounds[i]); was campsites.push(campgrounds[i].number);

Comment: Ok cool, which one did it pass? To fix those failures, change `campsites.push(campgrounds[i]);` to `campsites.push(campgrounds[i].number);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, string, number) {
  const campsites = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if(
    campgrounds[i].isReserved === false &&
    campgrounds[i].view === string &&
    campgrounds[i].partySize >= number
    ) {
      campsites.push(campgrounds[i].number);
    }
  }
  return array.length
   ? array
   : "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your 
    party";
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).